# Oreo disabling autofill lint security error

Tags: android, lint, autofill, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm doing kind of a code cleanup and using Android Studio's Inspection/Analyze feature, for the following line:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setImportantForAutofill(android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS);
```

it's yelling as "Android Lint: Security Incorrect constant", ridiculously like:

> Must be one of: android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_AUTO,
>   android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_YES,
>   android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO,
>   android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_YES_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS,
>   android.view.View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS

Is this some sort of known bugs of Android, do yo have any idea or see that before?